# DJANGO: How can I duplicate attribute from other class?

Tags: python, django

I want to duplicate an attribute from other class.

```
class PedidoCliente(Pedido):

    total_pagado = models.DecimalField(blank=True, max_digits=10, decimal_places=2,default = 0,verbose_name="Pagado $") # default 0 para el error for += int
    barril_encargado = models.DecimalField(blank=True, default=0, max_digits=10, decimal_places=2,verbose_name="Barr. entregados")    
    fecha_entrega = models.DateField(verbose_name="Fecha Entrega")

class DetallePedidoCliente(DetallePedido):    
    comments = models.CharField(max_length=300, verbose_name="Comentarios")
    precio_venta = models.DecimalField(max_digits=16, decimal_places=2, default = 0)
    pedido = models.ForeignKey(PedidoCliente,on_delete=models.CASCADE)   

    fecha_entrega = the same from PedidoCliente
```

I'm new at OPP so sorry if it's a silly question.

Thanks!

Comment: The answer is don't. You already have a foreign key to the other model, you would just be storing redundant data otherwise.

Comment: Thanks. And which is the best way to do this? Merging the two tables in db?

Answer (score 0):

One should not look to mirror fields of another model. This simply leads to extra work. One needs to update this mirrored field each time it is updated in the other table, etc.

Also it is not very useful when we have already cemented the relationship between the two tables using a Foreign Key.

To access a related fields data is very easy in Django. Suppose we have an instance of `DetallePedidoCliente` named `instance` using this we can access the `fecha_entrega` of the related model by the foreign key as follows:

```
instance.pedido.fecha_entrega
```

If one just wants an easy way to refer to this field one may consider adding a `property` to the model:

```
class DetallePedidoCliente(DetallePedido):    
    comments = models.CharField(max_length=300, verbose_name="Comentarios")
    precio_venta = models.DecimalField(max_digits=16, decimal_places=2, default = 0)
    pedido = models.ForeignKey(PedidoCliente,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
    @property
    def fecha_entrega(self):
        return self.pedido.fecha_entrega
```

Now we can simply access the field as:

```
instance.fecha_entrega
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I didn't understand one thing. I want that the new "fecha_entrega" from DetallePedidoCliente be in the database as a column. I didn't understand how from property I can create that new "fecha_entrega" field.

Comment: @SilvioAranda Why do you want it as a column in the database? It is already present in the other table.